# Bootstrap-Multiselect: Dropdown is underneatch outer container if overflow-y is used

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using Bootstrap-Multiselect ([link](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/)) ... when the outer container has a overflow-y: scroll and a max-height ... the dropdown of the multiselect disappears. How can I get it to be displayed over filter-container?

HTML:

```
<div class="container filter-container">    

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 search-box">          
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form role="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group search-form-group">
            <label class="search-label">Users:</label>
            <div class="mid-width">
              <select class="select-users form-control"></select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>    
      </div>                                                                                        
  </div>  
 </div>  

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.filter-container {
    padding: 1%;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select-users').multiselect({
        maxHeight: 400,
        buttonWidth: '100%' 
    });
    var accounts = [
        { label: 'UserID 1', value: '1' },
        { label: 'UserID 2', value: '2' },      
        { label: 'UserID 3', value: '3' }, 
        { label: 'UserID 4', value: '4' },         
        { label: 'All', value: '' }  
        ];  

    $('.select-users').multiselect('dataprovider', accounts);  
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x78aopv7/)

I think this https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/382 addresses the issue as well.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you need overflow-y in the first place? With max-height set and overflow-y on that div it will always apear within that container

Comment: I have a group of mulitselects in the filter-container (about 15) ... and due to the amount the filter-container gets very long ... that's why I wanted to overflow-y: scroll it ... . The .filter-container is also a collabsable container

Comment: You can use built-in html select which will go above the container but then you will not be using bs multiselect features, I would suggest redesigning the solution if thats still possible and/or expanding the height of the entire filters div, maybe overlaying everything in some kind of modal style box, I think that approach which you are trying is limited by browsers and html specs

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in your css

```
.multiselect-container {
  position:relative;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x78aopv7/13/)

Comment: ... but then the filter-container gets bigger (height) ... I want it to stay at max: 100px

Comment: In that case u need to put the dropdown outside the div,

Comment: ... but I would like to put it within the defined div .filter-container

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

under example 
[click](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)